# Error in xml file of image croper theartofdev library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, crop

I have an error in my `xml` file which i couldn't understand it is in the  image croper theartofdev library's crop image activity's xml file.

The error is at `<com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView` line and the error shows Can't find the declaration of element 'com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/cropImageView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:cropScaleType="center"/>
```

gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.smartloan.smtrick.smart_loan_admin"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dataBinding
        {
            enabled = true
        }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'

implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:1.2.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:+'
implementation project(':cropper')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: the error is at <com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView line and the error shows      Cannot find the declaration of element 'com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView'

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain the issue.

Comment: Then your problem is that the theartofdev lib is not loading properly. Please post your Gradle File!

Comment: Try to update a library. After that try Invalidate Cache and Restart.

Answer (score 0):

Can I get a look at your AndroidManifest.xml file? if you did not add the following line in the application tags, then it will not work.

```
<activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
```